# Lookahead for URL and User Agent in rather complex Logfile

Tags: python, regex

I have this Regex: http://regexr.com/39rbe

```
1413323829.0907|172.168.1.0|  |somedomain.com|OK|0015e248f2484591f52ed37030001|st=bla&cp=huh%2Cs_de%2Cf_bt%2Ce_rc%2Ch_sub%2Cl_ol%2Ca_noapp%2Cp_npaid%2Ci_t-e&sv=i2&pt=CP&rf=www.google.de&r2=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2F&ur=mydomain.de&xy=1366x768x24&lo=DE%asdaasdasdcb=0009&vr=306&id=guccjs&lt=1413373830843&ev=&cs=w2dwmo&mo=1&la=1413773766|i00=0615e248f8484591f52ed47030001%3B543e5f46%3B55966cde|Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/527.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2162.124 Safari/527.36|http://mydomain.de/uriPath|023|web|OK|OK
```

I am trying to capture the User Agent string where the URL equals `http://mydomain.de/uriPath`, e.g. does not work yet:

`[^\|]+(?=https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+)`

Comment: Split by `|` (even better if you use csv library), then check that the domain matches the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
\|[^|]+\|(?=https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+)
```

The for example: http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/5

If you dont want the  starting and trailling `|` , add those to a look around assertions as

```
(?<=\|)[^|]+(?=\|https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+)
```

giving output as

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/527.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2162.124 Safari/527.36
```

**What it does?**

`(?<=\|)` asserts that the following regex is presceded by `|`

`[^|]+` matches anything other than `|`

`(?=\|https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+)` asserts that *anything other than `|` * is followed by `|http://mydomain.de/uriPath|`

**EDIT**

Using capturing groups

```
\|([^|]+)\|(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+)
```

Comment: No need for an assertion. `\|([^|]+)\|(?=https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+)` does suffice, demo: http://regex101.com/r/kY1uS5/1

Comment: @SirBenBenji By the way, `(?=https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+)` is an assertion.

Comment: @SirBenBenji capturing groups is also fine sometimes better in reducing the lookaround overheads. I got a clear picture of lookarounds lately that i have a tendency to use them in my regex. sorry for that. wil add them in my answer. Thank you :)

Comment: What I meant, there seems no need for an additional one, e.g. `(?<=\|)`

Comment: assertions would increases the complexity.

Comment: If you are talking of Time Complexity T, then I would agree.

Comment: it takes more number of steps for debugging. You could check this in the linked demo site.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like below,

```
[^|]+(?=\|[^\|]*(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/6)

**OR**

Use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html),

```
\|([^|]+)\|[^\|]*(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/7)

```
>>> s = "1413323829.0907|172.168.1.0|  |somedomain.com|OK|0015e248f2484591f52ed37030001|st=bla&cp=huh%2Cs_de%2Cf_bt%2Ce_rc%2Ch_sub%2Cl_ol%2Ca_noapp%2Cp_npaid%2Ci_t-e&sv=i2&pt=CP&rf=www.google.de&r2=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2F&ur=mydomain.de&xy=1366x768x24&lo=DE%asdaasdasdcb=0009&vr=306&id=guccjs&lt=1413373830843&ev=&cs=w2dwmo&mo=1&la=1413773766|i00=0615e248f8484591f52ed47030001%3B543e5f46%3B55966cde|Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/527.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2162.124 Safari/527.36|http://mydomain.de/uriPath|023|web|OK|OK"
>>> re.search(r'\|([^|]+)\|[^\|]*(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+', s).group(1)
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/527.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2162.124 Safari/527.36'
```

Through splitting,

```
import re
s = "1413323829.0907|172.168.1.0|  |somedomain.com|OK|0015e248f2484591f52ed37030001|st=bla&cp=huh%2Cs_de%2Cf_bt%2Ce_rc%2Ch_sub%2Cl_ol%2Ca_noapp%2Cp_npaid%2Ci_t-e&sv=i2&pt=CP&rf=www.google.de&r2=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2F&ur=mydomain.de&xy=1366x768x24&lo=DE%asdaasdasdcb=0009&vr=306&id=guccjs&lt=1413373830843&ev=&cs=w2dwmo&mo=1&la=1413773766|i00=0615e248f8484591f52ed47030001%3B543e5f46%3B55966cde|Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/527.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2162.124 Safari/527.36|http://mydomain.de/uriPath|023|web|OK|OK"
L = s.split('|')
previous = ''
for i in L:
    if re.match(r'[^\|]*(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?mydomain\.de[^\|]+', i):
        print(previous)
    previous = i
```

**Output:**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/527.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2162.124 Safari/527.36
```

Comment: I want to grep the User Agent, not the URL.

Comment: Yes that works now, yet, there's still a lookahead in your answer.

Comment: added another one using capturing groups.